# Пространство имён для CSS

Tags: html, css

Есть файл css шаблона и есть файл css библиотеки, они конфликтуют.
Как решить эту проблему? 
Может быть можно как-то сделать *быстро* отдельное пространство имён для css файла сторонней библиотеки?

Answer (score 0):

[Munch.js](https://github.com/jmrocela/munchjs)

Munch.js - утилита, которая перезаписывает классы и идентификаторы в файлах CSS, HTML и JavaScript, чтобы сэкономить драгоценные байты и запутать ваш код. Основанный на [Craig Campbell's](https://craig.is/), [HTML-Muncher](http://htmlmuncher.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Можно, допустим, создать файл Less (или, наверное, другого препроцессора, но я с другими не работала) и написать там что-то вроде

```
.my-class {
    сюда вставить все стили библиотеки 
}
```

или

```
#my-id {
     сюда вставить все стили библиотеки 
 }
```

Скомпилировать Less в Css, таким образом, все стили будут предварены именем класса или идентификатора.

B HTML коде ту часть кода, где используется библиотека, положить в

```
<div class="my-class"></div>
```

или

```
<div id="my-id"></div>
```

Таким образом, получится что-то вроде пространства имен.